# A intersect B intersect C : Still confused

Tags: probability

I have the following question with A intersect B intersect C

I've broken down the formula below but I am stuck on $\mathbb{P}(B|\ A)$ below

---

$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(A) ~=~& 0.4
\\[2ex]
\mathbb{P}(B) ~=~&0.2
\\[2ex]
\mathbb{P}(C) ~=~&0.05
\\[2ex]
\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)
~=~ & \mathbb{P}((A \cap B) \cap C) 
\\[1ex]
=~ & \mathbb{P}(C\mid A \cap B) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) 
\\[1ex]
=~ & \mathbb{P}(C\mid A \cap B ) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B \mid A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A)
\end{align}$

---

I'm confused by $\mathbb{P}(B \mid A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A)$, because when I look for the formula to solve $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ I'm brought back to the formula $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$. How do I solve for either $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ or $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ if they are same?

Any breakdown or help would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume you are looking for $P(A\cap B\cap C)$. I don't believe there is enough information to solve this as it is posted. Have you provided all the information/the entire problem? You can [edit] your post to include more information at any time. Also, please learn to type up your posts properly. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think some information is missing. You have done as much as you can, now you need some more information on joint events.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments, still learning the formats on here. I'm using Latex but formatting here is a still new. What information am I missing. It's a long multi step project. I calculated the probability of events a, b, c based on 2 sets of data. Set A n = 6 , Set b n= 3, and a, b, c are events against these sets.

Comment: With $P(A)=0.4$ and $P(B)=0.2$ it is possible that $P(A\cap B)$ is literally anything between $0$ and $0.2$.  Without more information, you cannot know what the value is.  For example, let the experiment be that you have ten balls labeled 1 through 10.  You pick one of the balls uniformly at random.  In the case that $A$ is the event that you picked a number between 1 and 4 and $B$ is the event that you picked a $1$ or $2$, you have $P(A\cap B)=0.2$.  In the case that $A$ is the event that you picked a number between $1$ and $4$ and $B$ is the event you picked a $9$ or $10$ its $P(A\cap B)=0$

Comment: If you can tell us what the experiment is and what the events $A,B,C$ each represent, perhaps we could tell you more.  Without context, you would need to know one of $P(A\cap B),P(A\mid B),P(B\mid A)$ in order to know the other two.

Comment: Ah, so you're asking if the events are independent? That's another question I had, how can I mathematically see if 2 events are independent or dependent on each other?

Comment: If you know the independence of the events, that would work as well, however that is just a rewording of knowing one of the aforementioned three pieces of information.  Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if and only if $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ if and only if $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a Venn diagram lurking in the background of this. For example, if $A \supset B \supset C,$ then you could do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of some gaps and confusion, maybe I can give you a start with some of this.

For simplicity of notation, I will adopt the frequently used convention of writing intersection as 'products'. That is, I'll write $A \cap B$ as $AB$, etc.

1. As mentioned in a couple of comments, you need more information to give a specific 
   numerical value for $P(ABC).$ It could be $0$ or $.05$ or anything between.
   Do you understand these two possible boundary values?
2. $P(ABC) = P((AB)C)$ because $ABC$ and $(AB)C$ mean the same thing. (Associative rule for set intersection.)
3. $P(C|AB)P(AB) = \frac{P(ABC)}{P(AB)}P(AB) = P(ABC),$
   by the definition of conditional probability.
4. Similarly the last product of three factors is also equal to $P(ABC).$
   Can you write this out on your own?

Note: I have the feeling you are just beginning to study these ideas, and that you
have left something out, especially for the first item. Please fill in gaps or ask additional specific questions, if you need more explanation.